# How do I access the timeit magic function directly

Tags: python, ipython

I want to run timing on a larger scale and output dataframes of results from the iPython `%timeit` magic function.  I don't want to rewrite it.  How should I access directly?

I'd like something like this:

```
f = lambda x: (x * 4. + 2) ** .5

for i in xrange(3):
    print timeit(f(i))
```

And I'd get some output:

```
100 loops: 1 s
10 loops: 10 s
10 loops: 3e9 ns
```

Or similar.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could import the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module and manually specify the number of iterations:

```
from timeit import timeit

f = lambda x: (x * 4. + 2) ** .5

for i in xrange(3):
    num = 100
    print  '%s: %s'%(num, timeit('f(i)', number=num))
```

You can use [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat) instead of putting your timer in a loop